# (Internal Error) Opening Android Studio in School Computer

Tags: android, android-studio, installation

I have declared both system and user environment variables and setup everything I thought was needed. Getting this screen when attempting to open:
I have reinstalled Android Studio with admin privileges. Still nothing.
[image]

Does anyone know what the problem is? Let me know if information is insufficient.

edit 1: copyable error message

```
Internal Error. Please report to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing 'com.intellij.debugger.DebuggerManager'
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.handleComponentError(PluginManager.java:256)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.PlatformComponentManagerImpl.handleInitComponentError(PlatformComponentManagerImpl.java:43)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:540)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.createComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.java:123)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.init(ComponentManagerImpl.java:107)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.init(ComponentManagerImpl.java:90)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectImpl.init(ProjectImpl.java:282)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerImpl.initProject(ProjectManagerImpl.java:231)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerImpl.access$300(ProjectManagerImpl.java:68)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerImpl$3.run(ProjectManagerImpl.java:311)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:446)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:392)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeNonCancelableSection(CoreProgressManager.java:170)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerImpl.getDefaultProject(ProjectManagerImpl.java:306)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.IdeSdks.getAndroidSdkPath(IdeSdks.java:90)
    at com.android.tools.idea.startup.GradleSpecificInitializer.setupSdks(GradleSpecificInitializer.java:282)
    at com.android.tools.idea.startup.GradleSpecificInitializer.run(GradleSpecificInitializer.java:114)
    at com.android.tools.idea.AndroidInitialConfigurator.activateAndroidStudioInitializerExtensions(AndroidInitialConfigurator.java:198)
    at com.android.tools.idea.AndroidInitialConfigurator.<init>(AndroidInitialConfigurator.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.InstantiatingComponentAdapter.newInstance(InstantiatingComponentAdapter.java:193)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter$1.run(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:220)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.java:53)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:248)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:499)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.createComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.java:123)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.access$801(ApplicationImpl.java:92)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$12.run(ApplicationImpl.java:500)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:142)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:446)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:392)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:127)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.createComponents(ApplicationImpl.java:516)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.init(ComponentManagerImpl.java:107)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:458)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:450)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:197)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1$1$1.run(MainImpl.java:52)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:366)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jdi/Value
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy47.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.util.EventDispatcher.<init>(EventDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.intellij.util.EventDispatcher.create(EventDispatcher.java:42)
    at com.intellij.debugger.impl.DebuggerStateManager.<init>(DebuggerStateManager.java:29)
    at com.intellij.debugger.impl.DebuggerManagerImpl$MyDebuggerStateManager.<init>(DebuggerManagerImpl.java:606)
    at com.intellij.debugger.impl.DebuggerManagerImpl$MyDebuggerStateManager.<init>(DebuggerManagerImpl.java:606)
    at com.intellij.debugger.impl.DebuggerManagerImpl.<init>(DebuggerManagerImpl.java:81)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.InstantiatingComponentAdapter.newInstance(InstantiatingComponentAdapter.java:193)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter$1.run(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:220)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.java:53)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:248)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:499)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jdi.Value
    at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader.findClass(UrlClassLoader.java:207)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 80 more
```

edit 2: my JAVA_HOME user variable

[image: JAVA_HOME variable]

Does it have to be like this in system variables as well?

Comment: Can you copy-paste the complet error message, not a screenshot please ?

Comment: Updated question. I do not have admin privileges.

Comment: Maybe like the message says : Report this error to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues. Probably you will have a better answer !

Comment: you should also update your question title.

Comment: check this link same issue has being reported in code.google:  https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=211766

Comment: Maybe related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39686051/android-studio-wont-start-com-sun-jdi-value-not-found

Comment: try installing with admin privileges. and your system is 64bit or 32bit?

Comment: 32bit, I will try installing it with admin privileges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to fix this issue, please ensure your JAVA_HOME is pointing to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102 (Java SE Development Kit) instead of C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_102 (Java SE Runtime Environment).
In fact, JRE is located inside JDK folder.

If you haven't installed JDK yet, please do it following next link: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html?ssSourceSiteId=otnes

Got from:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=211766

Comment: Updated question.

Comment: in command prompt type this 'java -version' to check java is installed properly or not

Comment: It's installed properly, do you have any other ideas?

Comment: set the jdk path like this 'c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\' in some cases path.check this link fully http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574189/android-studio-installation-on-windows-7-fails-no-jdk-found?rq=1

Comment: I don't think I had a JDK_PATH variable set up at all. It works now. I've been tampering with this for weeks. Thank you so much for taking time out of your day to help! :D

Answer (score 1):

It's a JDK issue with Android Studio.

Try to set `JAVA_HOME` to JDK folder

And to set `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` to the Path environment variable with the JAVA_HOME environment variable pointing to the jdk folder.

> **Remember note**: You might need to restart Windows after changing the environment variable

Sources :

- [code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=211766](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=211766)
- [Android Studio Won't Start (com.sun.jdi.Value Not Found)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39686051/android-studio-wont-start-com-sun-jdi-value-not-found)
- [How to set java_home on Windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619584/how-to-set-java-home-on-windows-7)

Comment: Updated question.

Comment: @S5amuel Updated Answer :)

Comment: My user variables have been set up that way since before I asked the question. Not really sure what I can do.

Comment: @S5amuel Use the third link in my post if you don't know how to change Environment Variables in 'System' in the control panel , and come back with the result (i hope good)

Comment: Teacher gave me admin privileges. Added JAVA_HOME and PATH with correct values in both user and system variables to no avail.

Comment: Reinstalled android studio as admin and still nothing.

Comment: I can only advise to recheck twice all things, you are probably close to the solution (if based on what people say who had the same problem)

Comment: yes @S5amuel try uninstalling the jdk install freshly set the path, restart your system. do all this with admin privileges. or try on some other system in your school.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning on HAXM at the boot time of your pc and checking all the required plugins of Android studio.
Thanks..